# RoR: Output Hash, getting correct parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have output something like this:

```
#<Hashie::Mash created_time="1366008641" 
from=#<Hashie::Mash full_name="Cor Valen" id="22340" username="_corin"> 
id="4344344286" text="Look Who It Is, My Brother, My Favorite Deputy">
```

This was an output if I did this:

```
<%= media.caption %>
```

I wanted to get the `text` part, and I did this:

```
<%= media.caption.text %> 
gets me error: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

<%= media.caption[:text] %>
gets me error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't get it?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the hash that you are passing to Hashie::Mash

Comment: @Anand What do you mean? I'm trying to get the text, but when using caption, I get that hash output.

Comment: What I mean is when using media.caption you are getting back a Hashie::Mash object, which part of your code is handling that? Instagram passes data in JSON format, which when parsed returns a normal Hash object.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Instagram feeds, and I found that certain media items did not have a caption, so threw the error.

I solved this using:

```
<% unless media.caption.blank? %>
  <%= media.caption.text %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume media is this object. What's the caption? I don't see any param like this in your object, so why do you assume it exists? It's pretty obvious, it throws undefined method '[...]' for nil:NilClass, since your attribute does NOT exist.

You're probably looking for `media.from.text`, not `media.caption.text`.

Comment: Look properly at the output, the "text" attribute is not a part of the object that the attribute "from" refers to, so `media.from.text` will also not work.

Comment: Oh, it's probably too early for me. Haven't noticed this closing tag... So... `media.text` then, as this attribute belongs to main object?

Comment: I get that hash error because I'm using media.caption. So I was assuming that the hash error was outputting what is inside caption? But if that is not the case, then I'll try media.text. But that doesn't make sense because I'm trying to figure out based on the response from the `/media/popular` here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/ where `caption` is in the data json, which is `media.caption`?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the JSON from the link you gave and ran it through `irb`, please see the output:

```
irb(main):004:0> media = Hashie::Mash.new(JSON.parse(File.open("inst.json").read))
=> #<Hashie::Mash data=[#<Hashie::Mash caption=#<Hashie::Mash created_time="1296656006" from=#<Hashie::Mash full_name="" id="1127272" type="user" username="cocomiin"> id="26329105" text="This is dummy text."> comments=#<Hashie::Mash> created_time="1296655883" filter="Gotham" id="22518783" images=#<Hashie::Mash low_resolution=#<Hashie::Mash height=306 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_6.jpg" width=306> standard_resolution=#<Hashie::Mash height=612 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_7.jpg" width=612> thumbnail=#<Hashie::Mash height=150 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_5.jpg" width=150>> likes=#<Hashie::Mash count=35 data=[#<Hashie::Mash full_name="Kevin S" id="4" profile_picture="" username="mikeyk">, #<Hashie::Mash>]> link="http://instagr.am/p/BV5v_/" location=nil tags=[] type="image" user=#<Hashie::Mash full_name="Cocomiin" id="1127272" profile_picture="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1127272_75sq_1296145633.jpg" username="cocomiin">>]>
irb(main):005:0> media = media.data[0]
=> #<Hashie::Mash caption=#<Hashie::Mash created_time="1296656006" from=#<Hashie::Mash full_name="" id="1127272" type="user" username="cocomiin"> id="26329105" text="This is dummy text."> comments=#<Hashie::Mash> created_time="1296655883" filter="Gotham" id="22518783" images=#<Hashie::Mash low_resolution=#<Hashie::Mash height=306 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_6.jpg" width=306> standard_resolution=#<Hashie::Mash height=612 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_7.jpg" width=612> thumbnail=#<Hashie::Mash height=150 url="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_5.jpg" width=150>> likes=#<Hashie::Mash count=35 data=[#<Hashie::Mash full_name="Kevin S" id="4" profile_picture="" username="mikeyk">, #<Hashie::Mash>]> link="http://instagr.am/p/BV5v_/" location=nil tags=[] type="image" user=#<Hashie::Mash full_name="Cocomiin" id="1127272" profile_picture="http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1127272_75sq_1296145633.jpg" username="cocomiin">>
irb(main):006:0> media.caption.text
=> "This is dummy text."
```

Comment: It is so weird. I mean media.caption.text should work. but I'm getting method text nil. arg!